# How to dump the data behind a hash reference

Tags: perl, reference

I am trying to debug some legacy Perl code, and I am using `Data::Dumper` to help.

I have the following variables and I'm not sure how to pass these to `Data::Dumper` to print their contents

```
$Class    = $$Contents{'Class'}{$value};     
$Category = $$Contents{'Category'}{$value};
```

I want to dump out the `$Contents` hash reference. How do I do this?

I want to see what values are present in the `$Class` hash and the `$Category` hash.

Comment: Have you tried `print Dumper($Contents)` ?

Comment: When you say "errors out", what *exactly* do you mean? Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51968379/edit) to add the text of the error message. It would also be helpful if you could include a cut-down version of your code that we could run to see the error.

Comment: I'm always surprised by people who treat error or warning messages as if they were flies to be swatted away. *"errors out"* means that there was a *message* which more or less says exactly why your program failed. The contents of those messages are essential information if you are asking for help with your code, as is the code itself. Please read [*How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and try to understand that it is *essential* to provide as much information as possible.

Comment: Hi Dave, sorry the errors out was incorrect, I meant its not showing what I expected. Fixed in the question.

Comment: @Borodin when I said error it was actually incorrect. There was no error. It wasnt doing what I expected, wrong wording in the original question which has since been fixed.

Comment: *"It did'nt show the sub hash values of Class and Category"* You are mistaken. I can't think of any way that is possible, unless perhaps if `$Contents` is a tied hash.

Comment: Your update isn't part of your question. Please use comments to comment on answers or on your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didnt get exactly what I wanted, aka for Dumper to just output everything from the parent hash, but I did find a workaround by dumping the sub hashes.

Doing the following didnt achieve what I needed

```
print Dumper $Contents
```

It didnt show the sub hash values of class and category. This I know as when I print Class and Category they have values that are not shown when Dumper prints the Contents var.

However I have been able to output the individual hash values as follows:

```
print Dumper $Contents->{'Class'};
print Dumper $Category->{'Category'};
```

Not what I originally wanted to do, but it works.

Answer (score 4):

`%Contents`, `$Contents`, and `@Contents` are completely unrelated; after all their names are very different!

You need simply `print Dumper $Contents`

It would help to use modern syntax and write the hash access as

```
$Contents->{Category}{$value}
```